# AngularJS ng-repeat certain filter expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Here's what I have:

```
<div data-ng-if="hasSelectedCompany">
   <tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in result.applications | filter: { name: selectedApplication } track by $index">
</div>
<div data-ng-if="hasSelectedSupportedCompany">
   <tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in result.applications | filter: { name: selectedSupportedApplication } track by $index">
</div>
```

And I know this can be improved, I'm just not sure how.  It's not working right now.  The first expression is not working when I have both of these in there.  When I remove the second expression completely, the first one starts to work.  The second one works with both of them in.

What's an alternative way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide plunker of jsfiddle jow it not working?

Answer (score 2):

Both filters will not work together because both are referring to same `result.applications`.

You need to do separate the filtered array of both by assigning it to different variable like `applicationsForCompany` for `hasSelectedCompany` div & `applicationsForSupportedCompany` for `hasSelectedSupportedCompany` div

**Markup**

```
<div data-ng-if="hasSelectedCompany">
   <tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in applicationsForCompany = (result.applications | filter: { name: selectedApplication }) track by $index">
</div>
<div data-ng-if="hasSelectedSupportedCompany">
   <tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in applicationsForSupportedCompany =  (result.applications | filter: { name: selectedSupportedApplication }) track by $index">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  Is there any way to make this work with a shared variable?  I have some logic below this where I'm doing another ng-repeat based on the first results.

Comment: The first one still doesn't seem to work unless I remove the second expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search1">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data|filter:{name:search}">{{d.name}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="d in data|filter:{name:search1}">{{d.name}}</div>
  </body>

</html>

angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.data = [{id:1,name:'cata',surname:'obreja'},{id:2,name:'dani',surname:'popa'},{id:3,name:'Sir',surname:'dani'}];
}]);
```

Here is an example that works but i don't know for sure if it is what you are looking for.
Here is the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/W7ZofMcZMKTfw3BUB4jX?p=preview